# Fail to download file using SCP

Tags: scp

I am trying to download a large number of files from a remote Ubuntu Server to my machine which is also running on Ubuntu. I am using SCP protocol as below:

```
for i in *; do $i sshpass -p 'Remote_Server_Passcode' scp root@<Remote_Server_IP>:'/opt/Data/' .; done
```

This is failing with an error message saying `command not found`

Any help pointing towards right direction will be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Start simple. How would you download a single file?

Comment: For a single file my approach is "sshpass -p 'Password' scp root@IP:'/opt/Data/*aa.txt' ."

Comment: Not `*aa.txt sshpass -p 'Password' scp root@IP:'/opt/Data/'`? Because that's what your loop does.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to copy the whole `/opt/Data` directory, this can also be achieved like this:

```sh
scp -r root@<Remote_Server_IP>:/opt/Data/ .
```

- `-r` means recursive

And as to what was going wrong the `for i in *; do $i` loops through all files in the current *local* directory and then tries to execute those, which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Hi 0x76, when you say "-r means recursive", does it exclude all Folders and only consider files? I dont want to disturb any Folder in my Local machine. Also, how can I properly set 'i' so that it can loop through Remote folder, not local. I tried with "for i in root@< Remote_Server_IP >:'/opt/Data/'; do $i", but it doesn t seem to be correct approach

Comment: The `-r` will copy the exact folder/file structure from your server locally. If you want to use wildcard expansion on the remote, the command would be something like this: `scp root@<Remote_Server_IP>:/opt/Data/\* .`